# created project appears in php dir

Tags: zend-framework

I try to create a zf project but the project appears in my php dir.

I use zf version 1.9.2

I have the zf.bat and zf.php copied to:

k:\xampp\php\zf.php and k:\xampp\php\zf.bat
I use windows xp.

But it creates the project in my php dir in stead of in my webroot.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invoke the command from the folder you want to create the project in. This would look something like:

```
k:\xampp\htdocs> zf create myproject
```

In order to be able to use the client script from everywhere in your folder structure you have to add zf.bat to your system path.

If you don't know how to do that I recommend [Redmond Path](http://redmondlab.googlepages.com/path) which lets you manage entries in the system paths with ease.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to copy and the paste the project :) easy isn't ?

What i think is probably the better solution:

Put your php.exe and zf.bat in your path (SYSTEM PATH) so you can execute its command from anywhere you like:

Go to system properties -> advanced tab -> environment variables button -> 
then choose the "path" form system variables and add the path to your PHP.exe and ZF.bat

Looks something like this

```
D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6;D:\Workspace\Zend\ZF\bin;D:\Workspace\Zend\PHPUnit
```

DONT forget to add the ";" between every executable ! .

once you did this .. and form your webroot dir you can execute any ZF Tool Command you like

Comment: Sorry for my bad english ,
and thanks you  tharkun for this improve .